# Are there any points of no return?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

In a Mass Effect game there is normally a point of no return, for example in Mass Effect 2 you could inadvertently lose several ship mates by not doing the Collector mission straight away. Mass Effect 1 had Ilos and Mass Effect 3 had multiple groups of missions that would be unavailable if you didn't do the game in a particular order (like Grissom, Priority: Tuchanka, etc).

Are there any points of no return in Mass Effect: Andromeda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously this answer contains spoilers.

Mass Effect Andromeda works a little bit differently to previous Mass Effect games in this regard.

The one hard quest lockout is on Eledaan, the Krogan colony will task you with getting the Drive from a crashed Remnant vessel. If you refuse to give them the drive core after obtaining it, then you will not be allowed to establish an outpost on Eledaan. This means that you cannot complete the quest to find all the ZK Tracker stations and you will be unable to find and kill the Architect on Eledaan.

The only confirmed report for a quest not working after the game is complete is Liam's Movie Night quest. A large number of people have reported that the quest just breaks after completing the final quest.

Now, on the subject of the final quest. Technically, you can just follow the Priority Missions all the way to the end and do it as fast as possible. However, depending on quests completed in the game, you get extra support from various factions when assaulting Meridian.

You will get support from the angara regardless of the extra quests you complete. However, depending on how you complete A Trail of Hope, you can get more support. And if you complete a certain side quest, the support is more effective at killing enemies.

Apart from the hard lockout on Eledaan and the bugged quest, every other quest can be completed after the end game. You will miss out on dialogue and support however.